# Java EE Interceptor causing a transaction rollback

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, interceptor

I'm playing around with Java EE. Here is my Monitoring Interceptor:

```
public class MonitoringInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object monitorMethodCall(InvocationContext ctx) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Exception exception = null;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  // FIXME: use nanotime
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e){
            exception = e;
            throw e; // <- PROBLEM
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            log(ctx, duration, exception );
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

And then I'm using this interceptor in all my beans:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors({MonitoringInterceptor.class})
public class BeanA {
   [...]
}

@Stateless
@Interceptors({MonitoringInterceptor.class})
public class BeanB {

   @EJB
   private BeanA beanA;

   public void doit(){
       try {
          beanA.dosomeThing();
       } catch(Exception e) {

          // handle...
       }
   }
}
```

The problem now, if I call the method `BeanB#doit()` and `BeanA#dosomeThing()` throws an exception, my Interceptor will catch the exception to log the error, pass it through and then **my transaction get rolled back** [!].

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What would you expect it to do? This has nothing to do with your interceptor. An exception means that something went wrong, and in those cases (unless explicitly specified) the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: ok, every bean will get its own transaction right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "every bean gets its own transaction". A transaction context is defined for a thread of execution, whether there's any transaction context active (or even multiple ones in the case of `REQUIRES_NEW`) depends on your [TransactionAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) configurations. By default every invocation of an EJB method will have a transaction context as if [REQUIRED](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRED) had been specified.

Comment: I mean every call of container bean. But thx I got it!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour if you dont want tx support dont use EJB's or annotate with [NotSupported](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#NOT_SUPPORTED) your EJB methods.